# How to workaround git clone out-of-memory by injecting remote data manually

Tags: git, out-of-memory

I want to clone a git repo on a remote shell with limited memory (1GB ram per user).

```
$ ulimit -a  
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 1000000  
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited  
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) 1000000

$ repo init -u git://github.com/CyanogenMod/android.git -b cm-11.0
$ repo sync
```

It breaks with this error messages:

```
fatal: Out of memory? mmap failed: Cannot allocate memory  
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly  
error: Cannot fetch CyanogenMod/android_frameworks_base
```

I already tried this git config without success:

```
pack.packsizelimit=256m  
pack.deltacachesize=256m  
pack.threads=1  
pack.windowmemory=256m  
core.packedgitlimit=256m  
core.packedgitwindowsize=256m
```

Now i've downloaded that remote repo data (snapshot) manually and extracted it with proper folder structure:

```
wget https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_frameworks_base/archive/cm-11.0.zip  
(817MB)
```

Is it possible to create the packfiles/references/links from that extracted data for the main .repo folder and continue with 'repo sync'?

Comment: I guess, what you've downloaded is not a git repo, but a snapshot.

Comment: You could clone it anywhere you like and just copy `.git` directory to remote machine with scp/ftp/whatever.

Comment: Yes, it's a snapshot. Copying .git folder is not an option. The question is if its possible to create the .git folder (at least the pack files) manually from the snapshot data.

Comment: No. Why it's not an option?

Comment: I want to solve it all locally.

Comment: Obviously impossible. There is no information about commiters and previous versions of files.

Comment: You could try to do a shallow clone

Comment: That's weird. I've deleted everything, restarted from scratch and now it finished properly. Its possible that the previous `repo init --reference=~/Android/cm10.1 -u git://github.com/CyanogenMod/android.git -b cm-11.0` wasn't completely killed by new `repo init`.